# Creating a loop to print selected panels from a Lattice graph in independent pages

Tags: r, loops, plot, lattice

I have generated the following plot in lattice and latticeExtra
[image]

using

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)
rate$Temp <- as.character(rate$Temp)
rate$Week <- as.character(rate$Week)
rate$Rep <- as.character(rate$Rep)
histogram(~Rate|Week+Temp, rate, 
 col=(NA),as.table=TRUE, 
 strip=strip.custom(strip.names=1)) +as.layer
(bwplot(~Rate|Week+Temp, rate,
  as.table=TRUE,
  strip=strip.custom(strip.names=1))
 )
```

however I need each combination to be plotted in a different page, so that all temperature 11 for each week are in one page and so on. I know this can be done manually but there must be a way of using a loop to do it. Anyone??
Here is the data used to generate the plot

```
rate <- structure(list(Temp = c("11°C", "11°C", "11°C", "11°C", "11°C", 
"11°C", "11°C", "11°C", "11°C", "11°C", "11°C", "11°C", "11°C", 
"11°C", "11°C", "11°C", "13°C", "13°C", "13°C", "13°C", "13°C", 
"13°C", "13°C", "13°C", "13°C", "13°C", "13°C", "13°C", "13°C", 
"13°C", "13°C", "13°C", "15°C", "15°C", "15°C", "15°C", "15°C", 
"15°C", "15°C", "15°C", "15°C", "15°C", "15°C", "15°C", "15°C", 
"15°C", "15°C", "15°C"), Rep = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2"), Ind = c(12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), Week = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", 
"4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", 
"2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4"), Weight = c(0.2099, 0.2099, 
0.2099, 0.2099, 0.3483, 0.3483, 0.3483, 0.3483, 0.3724, 0.3724, 
0.3724, 0.3724, 0.2751, 0.2751, 0.2751, 0.2751, 0.2562, 0.2562, 
0.2562, 0.2562, 0.3842, 0.3842, 0.3842, 0.3842, 0.3206, 0.3206, 
0.3206, 0.3206, 0.4803, 0.4803, 0.4803, 0.4803, 0.7392, 0.7392, 
0.7392, 0.7392, 0.277, 0.277, 0.277, 0.277, 0.082, 0.082, 0.082, 
0.082, 0.5663, 0.5663, 0.5663, 0.5663), Rate = c(13.733, 9.322, 
12.46, 6.581, 2.338, 2.652, 2.772, 3.026, 1.554, 1.677, 2.127, 
2.102, 2.522, 2.476, 2.847, 2.999, 1.764, 2.442, 2.877, 2.976, 
2.479, 2.532, 2.874, 3.052, 1.724, 2.292, 2.405, 2.397, 1.553, 
3.385, 3.178, 2.959, 0.687, 0.808, 1.042, 1.033, 2.255, 2.755, 
2.878, 3.338, 4.515, 5.089, 7.349, 8.113, 1.185, 1.649, 2.382, 
1.989)), .Names = c("Temp", "Rep", "Ind", "Week", "Weight", "Rate"
), row.names = c(NA, -48L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This little loop will print you three different plots in rapid succession:

```
temps <- unique(rate$Temp)
temps

for (i in seq_along(temps)){
  #plot.new()
  rate_subset <- rate[rate$Temp==temps[i], ]
  print(histogram(~Rate|Week, rate_subset, 
      col=(NA),as.table=TRUE, 
      strip=strip.custom(strip.names=1)) +
      as.layer(bwplot(~Rate|Week, rate_subset,
            as.table=TRUE,
            strip=strip.custom(strip.names=1))
        ))
}
```

There are at least two ways of getting this into a second document:

- Ensure `recording` is set to TRUE in your R graphics device.  I use the RGui device, and in the `History` menu there is an option for this.  Then copy and paste as per normal.
- The second way is to use the `pdf` device:

  pdf(onefile=FALSE)
  print(histogram(...))
  device.off()

So then your loop becomes:

```
for (i in seq_along(temps)){
  rate_subset <- rate[rate$Temp==temps[i], ]
  pdf(onefile=FALSE)
  print(histogram(~Rate|Week, rate_subset, 
      col=(NA),as.table=TRUE, 
      strip=strip.custom(strip.names=1)) +
      as.layer(bwplot(~Rate|Week, rate_subset,
            as.table=TRUE,
            strip=strip.custom(strip.names=1))
        ))
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: I used trellis.device(), in this case you don't need to set the pdf(onefile=false) it will open a new graphic device for each plot